# Must declare the scalar variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy obteniendo este error y no entiendo porqué? según yo ya estoy declarando previamente **@PTI_R**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código actual

```
declare @Iva decimal(5,2) = (.16),
@tasaInteres decimal(10,2) ,
@fechaDispIni date,
@sueldoMensual decimal (20,2),
@dispIni decimal(20,2),
@PTI_R decimal(3,2)

set @PTI_R = 23

declare @PTI decimal(8,2) = @PTI_R * 100;
select @PTI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De la forma en que lo tienes escrito (un solo `DECLARE` con cada variable separada por coma), es una única línea de declaración de variables. Por lo mismo, en esa línea, la variable `@PTI_R` aún no existe.

Para solucionar tu error, simplemente declara la variable `@PTI` en un nuevo `DECLARE`:

```
declare @Iva decimal(5,2) = (.16),
        ...las otras variables acá,
        @PTI_R decimal(3,2);

declare @PTI decimal(8,2) = @PTI_R * 100;
```

Ahora, acá hay otro problema, y es que estás asignando el cálculo (`@PTI_R * 100`) antes de darle un valor a `@PTI_R`, por lo que el resultado de eso será `NULL`. Tendrías que hacer:

```
declare @Iva decimal(5,2) = (.16),
        ...las otras variables acá,
        @PTI_R decimal(3,2);

SET @PTI_R = 23;
declare @PTI decimal(8,2) = @PTI_R * 100;
```

Finalmente, un tercer problema (basado en tu comentario). `decimal(3,2)` significa que es un tipo de datos que tiene 3 dígitos **en total**, 2 de los cuales son para la parte **decimal** (después de la coma). Por lo tanto, el máximo número que puedes almacenar en ese tipo de dato es `9,99`, por lo que te lanza un error al tratar de asignarle el valor `23`.

Comment: **Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 8
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.** ... eso me tira

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: @PTI_R decimal(3,2); debe ser (x,2) donde x sea mayor a 3 para que entren los dígitos

Comment: claro, `decimal(4,2)` va a soportar datos hasta `99.99`