# SQL - Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, fetch, cursor

estoy intentando recorrer una tabla de nombres de bases de datos a los que les quiero sacar el tamaño de los ficheros, entre otras cosas.
Estoy usando un Cursor pero me da un error 
"Must declare the scalar variable @NombreBBDD" pero lo declaro antes.
Alguien me puede echar una mano?
Gracias

```
    DECLARE @tablaBBDD AS table(
      nombre nvarchar(50));
SELECT name INTO tablaBBDD FROM master.sys.databases;


DECLARE CursorBdd CURSOR local fast_forward FOR SELECT name FROM tablaBBDD;
OPEN CursorBdd;

DECLARE @NombreBBDD AS nvarchar(50);
SET @NombreBBDD='';
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorBdd INTO @NombreBBDD;

WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
BEGIN

PRINT @NombreBBDD
use @NombreBBDD
SELECT name, size/128.0 FileSizeInMB,
size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0 
   AS EmptySpaceInMB, max_size/128.0 MaxSizeMB, 
   CASE [is_percent_growth]    
        WHEN 1 THEN CAST(growth AS varchar(20)) + '%'
        WHEN 0 THEN CAST(growth*8/1024 AS varchar(20)) + 'Mb'
   END
FROM @NombreBBDD.sys.database_files;
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorBdd INTO @NombreDDBB
END

close CursorBdd
deallocate CursorBdd
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! , creo que esta pregunta que ya esta respondida podría interesarte [stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199328/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-sql)

Comment: O esto también: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177838/setear-variable-query-dinamico/177903#177903, básicamente no puedes hacer `USE @Variable` , a menos que escribas una sentencia dinámica